# C++, Linux, socket send performance

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

(Original issue listed below)
It turned out I had a "slow consumer" issue. Since I don't have control over the server program, I tried setting
  setsockopt(m_sock,
             IPPROTO_TCP,
                          TCP_NODELAY,
                          (char *) &flag,
                          sizeof(int));

but I still get to the point where write to the socket takes a few seconds.
Am I missing something?
Original Issue:
I've created a socket using

```
m_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Set it to non blocking:

```
int opts = fcntl ( m_sock, F_GETFL );

opts = ( opts | O_NONBLOCK ); 

fcntl ( m_sock, F_SETFL,opts );
```

and then send

```
send(m_sock, v_pData, v_iDataSize, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

I'm sending about 200bytes , 5 times a second
after about 2 minutes it creates a big buffer and a big delay in sending the data.
Is there a way to improve the send perofrmance?

**First Edit:**
I'm adding more code as for how I create and use the socket:

```
m_sock = socket ( AF_INET,
        SOCK_STREAM,
        0 );

if ( ! is_valid() )
  return false;

int on = 1;
if ( setsockopt ( m_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, ( const char* ) &on, sizeof ( on ) ) == -1 )
return false;


server = gethostbyname(host.c_str());
if (server == NULL) {   

    return false;
}
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
     server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

set_non_blocking(true);// Code for set_non_blocking mentioned above


connect(m_sock,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))  ;
```

I write to the socket using:

```
iOut = send(m_sock, v_pData, v_iDataSize, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

Comment: Show more code. How is computed `v_pData`? Did you compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and debug with `gdb` and `valgrind` ?

Comment: If delays are a problem, `TCP_NODELAY` might help. It looks like you are using `O_NONBLOCK` the wrong way. Do you understand what it means?

Comment: Where is it creating a big buffer as you mentioned in your question and how did you figure it out about the buffer size? Are you getting a successful connect btw?

Comment: The connections succeeds - I get the byte I write in a server

Answer (score 1):

You see the [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) in action.

Just set the TCP_NODELAY socket option:

```
int value = 1;
setsockopt(m_sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void*)&value, sizeof(value));
```

I don't think you need O_NONBLOCK, but that highly depends on your use case.

Comment: I've set the socket to TCP_NODELAY as described but I still get blocked at the write to the socket because of the "slow consumer"

Comment: @user1997268 When you have a "slow consumer", neither TCP_NODELAY, nor O_NONBLOCK may help. What do you mean with "slow consumer"? Just high latency, or is the consumer really slow consuming the data?

Answer (score 1):

Particularily if you use non-blocking I/O (e.g `O_NONBLOCK`) you should use some *multiplexing syscall* (like .e.g. [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or the older and obsolete `select(2)`) to ensure that your socket is indeed readable or writable (i.e. will succeed on [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or [recv(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) when readable, or on [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) or [send(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) when writable).

Of course, you'll need to multiplex several sockets if you have more than one.

In short you need an [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (you might use libraries providing one e.g. [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) ...), or have your own around a multiplexing syscall like `poll` ....). And even with one single bidirectional socket, you need to multiplex its input and its output (both with blocking or non-blocking I/O).

Read some good book, e.g. [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) 
and some [Linux Socket Tutorial](http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html) and the [Unix Network Programming](http://www.unpbook.com/) book.

Your question is not precise enough to be answered. You should give more code, or at least give the relevant `strace` traces on the suspicious syscalls.

Comment: In my opinion his problem is not related to non-blocking I/O.

Comment: I agree, but as you I did not understand the details of the original question (which is unclear).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch does the link for Advanced Linux Programming need updation?
Maybe the ACM(https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/558873) or OReilly(https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/advanced-linux-programming/0735710430/) link